# How come we write drought and draught but pronounce [draut] and [dra:ft] or write enough and though but pronounce [i’naf] and [đou]?

Tags: british-english, historical-change

How come we write drought and draught but pronounce [draut] and [dra: ft] or write enough and though but pronounce [i’naf] and [đou]?

Comment: Because it's English.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: the Great Vowel Shift.

Long answer: before the Great Vowel Shift began around 1400, there was a phoneme /x/ (written gh or  ȝh) in Middle English. By Modern English, /x/ had either mutated to /f/ or had become silent in standard dialects.

Long vowels had generally shifted to become various diphthongs. Vowels are notoriously slippery characters in the continuing tale of the GVS.

Comment: The long answer of yours is not very long.